# Getting the second row in a Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view. In this view, I got the row_num based on the productcontracted, InvoiceDate.

Can you please let me know how I can get the second row in each group?

[image: Example Table]

Answer (score 0):

As you've already got the row_number() setup how you want it, then all you need to do is filter on that row_number in the where statement. This often means turning your query into a subquery, something like the below.

```
    select * from 
    (
        <<your main query here>>
    )
    where row_number = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data it looks like you have already applied `row_number() over` in your query.
To get the second row is therefore: `row_number = 2` .
According to the highlighted rows you also want the row before last for each partition. To do this you can reverse the `order by` and then get the second row in each direction.
Your query will be something like the following

```
with cte as
( InvoiceDate,
  ProductContractId,
  row_number() over (
      partition by ProductContractId
      order by InvoiceDate asc) rn_forwards
  row_number() over (
      partition by ProductContractId
      order by InvoiceDate desc) rn_backwards )
select 
  InvocieDate,
  ProductContractId,
  rn_forwards,
  rn_backwards
from cte
where 
  rn_forwards = 2 
  or rn_backwards = 2;
```